# How not append if output already in text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run this code in a loop so it will give me all wifi details near me and save it in a file let's say output.txt but it should not save if a wifi detail is already in output.txt

```
if identify == "Windows":
    cmd = ["netsh", "wlan", "show", "networks", "mode=BSSID"]
    networks = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = networks.communicate()
    data = output.decode("utf-8")
    file = open("output.txt", "a")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    print(data)
    data.strip()
    f = open("output.txt", "r")
    read = f.read()
    read.strip()
    if data == read:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
f.close()
```

````
 
Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : Jiofi
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : c0:61:75:db:d1:08
         Signal             : 100%
         Radio type         : 652.11n
         Channel            : 6
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.4 54
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 87 24 36 30 54```
````

Comment: A textfile is probably not an ideal choice for what you want to do. You could consider putting the data into a `list` or a `dict` and then using `pickle` or maybe `json` to persist the data.

Comment: What does the printed data look like? is it a list of things? Can you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Interface name : Wi-Fi

There are 1 networks currently visible.



SSID 1 : Provider

    Network type            : Infrastructure

    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal

    Encryption              : CCMP

    BSSID 1                 :

         Signal             : 100%

         Radio type         : 

         Channel            : 

         Basic rates (Mbps) : 

         Other rates (Mbps) : 




----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: I removed some of the things cause it contails bssid and other details of my wifi

Comment: You need to define a `wifi detail`. What precisely is that? When you're done realizing what that is, you should perhaps define an object for it and store those objects in a `set`. After you're done searching, you can just dump the `set` contents into a `.txt` file.

Comment: if you want to know whats the output run this command in cmd "netsh wlan show networks mode=BSSID"

Comment: can you guyz give me a example code cause I am not getting that

Comment: Adding to what @CaptainTrojan said, set only stores unique values so it will automatically ignore any value which is already found in the set.

Comment: @ChristopherHolder I dont know how set works can you give me a sample code

Comment: What is identity? I would need sample data to do so. add it to your question and I will write some sample code

Comment: @ChristopherHolder I am new to this platform How to edit question?

Comment: Under your question it says edit. Click that button and modify your answer then save the changes.

Comment: @ChristopherHolder ya edited. Got it You are so helpfull sir

Comment: @CaptainTrojan can you help from here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn a list of strings into a set by doing `set(data)` which is equivalent to `set(['wifi1', 'wifi2', 'wifi3'])` and you can add a new item into the set by doing data.add(new_data).

However, if you plan to use that data it is probably smarter to save it in a pandas DataFrame, to which you can find the documentation here. [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

My preferred method of storage is an excel file because of the interface but if your data gets long enough then it will be harder to work with as it gets slow. But it work equally well with a .csv file.

I can't really give you any code to help you parse your string into a computer-readable format because I am not running the same operating system as you are and can't get that string there is plenty of specific documentation and tutorials out there.

This link might also be helpful to you: [Using pandas with python and CSV files](https://datatofish.com/import-csv-file-python-using-pandas/)

And this might be helpful to extract data from the string: [Python-E extract Words from Given String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extract-words-from-given-string/)

Answer (score 0):

You can purge your output file.

Split the output string by `SSID 1 :`  and make a dictionary where names of these SSID will be keys. Since dictionary can't have the same keys you will get only unique SSIDs:

```
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

contents = contents.split("SSID 1 : ")

dic = {}
for c in contents[1:]:
    dic[c.split("\n")[0]] = c

output = [contents[0]]
for k in dic:
    output.append("SSID 1 : " + dic[k])

with open("output_new.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(output))
```

To be precise the dict will contain last/newest SSIDs. Because every time a dictionary adds value with the old key it replaces old value of this key with new one. It makes sense in the most of cases. If you need to keep first/oldest SSIDs it can be done as well this way:

```
dic = {}
for c in contents[1:]:
    key = c.split("\n")[0]
    if key not in dic: dic[key] = c
```

I will store first SSIDs and will not update them.

---

Short version, almost an one-liner, just for fun:

```
with open("output.log", "r") as f: contents = f.read().split("SSID 1 : ")

dic = { b.split("\n")[0] : b for b in contents[1:] }
output = contents[0] + "".join([ "SSID 1 : " + dic[k] for k in dic ])

with open("output_new.log", "w") as f: f.write(output)
```